# chrome offline video speed

Tags: google-chrome-extension, html5-video, video-player

I've being downloading videos to watch for later because my network streaming speed is shit. because of lack of good video players on windows I want to play the downloaded video in chromium. Now there exist extensions that speed up html5 streaming video's speed. but those doesnt seem to work with offline .mp4 or even offline html, I've tried [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/video-speed-center/fiibghnadolodikeanlmjmiggapihopo/related?hl=en) extension amongst several others and its all the same. they seem to work for websites that uses a player of some sort, but doesn't work for the example on [w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp).

Why doesn't it work? Is there a work around?

Before some of you vote for irrelevance, I've already asked on meta exchange and looked on ubuntu exchange and found no solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use HTML5's own built-in [media playback rate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/playbackRate)?

This example is modified from W3School's example on [media playback rate](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_prop_playbackrate.asp):
(code is tested on Chrome browser only, hope it helps to solve your problem)...

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<body> 

<video id="vidObj" width="500" height="360" controls>
<source src="somevideofile.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

<script>

var myVid = document.getElementById("vidObj");

myVid.playbackRate = 0.672; //# some testing value
//# normal speed = 1.0; half speed = 0.5; double speed= 2.0; etc...

</script> 

</body> 
</html>
```